# Message: The name already exists in the tree: %0. Error in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, events, silverlight-4.0

I have a small problem with some a Silverlight app.

I have a Page with a navigation frame and 8 different pages. Each page displays a grid with some data, and each page has an update function implemented via `IUpdateUI` interface.

When the child page is loaded inside the navigation frame, the parent page obtains the IUpdateUI interface from the navigation frame's content. Every 30 seconds or so it will call the `Update()` function on that IUpdateUI interface thus forcing the child page to update itself. The concept is described in detail in this post: [How to declare an event handler in an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824771/how-to-declare-an-event-handler-in-an-interface)

However, i get a very weird error after five or six timer ticks and I have no clue what it means.:

Message: The name already exists in the tree: %0.

Any idea on how to mitigate this issue?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: How have you implemented "Update"? Are you dynamically loading XAML content? I think that error means a named XAML element is being loaded twice in the same visual tree.

Comment: The parent page has a timer. It also has a private reference to a `IUpdateUI` interface called `childPageInstance`. Each child displayed in the navigation frame implements the `IUpdateUI` interface which defines the `Update()` method. On the Navigated event of the frame displaying the child pages I grab an instance of the 'IUpdateUI' interface of the child page via the following code: `this.childPageInstance = (IUpdateUI)NavigationFrame.Content`. That works fine. Now in the tick event handler of the parent page I check `if( `this.childPageInstance != null){ this.childPageInstance.Update(); }`